# Do we learn any hilchos shechita from the Akeida?

Tags: halacha, midrash, slaughter-shochet-shecht, vayera, binding-of-isaac

The Binding of Isaac ([Gen. 22](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8217)) is a fascinating story, for a multitude of reasons.

One thing that appeals to me, as a *shochet* (slaughterer), is that it has in it (as far as I could tell) the earliest instance of the word "שחט" in the Torah ([22:10](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8217#v=10)).

I was wondering if the telling of the *Akeidah* contains within it anything for us practitioners of shechita, about the halachos of shechita.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16887/5323

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this is the only time that we learn halacha for shechita from the Binding of Isaac, but according to the [Simlah Chadasha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37555/5323) ([6:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=36&hilite=)), we learn that the shechita knife must be unattached from the ground in order to be eligible to use for shechita, from the *Akeidah*.

His source (ultimately), is the gemara, [Chulin 16a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=16&format=pdf):

> יתיב רב אחוריה דרבי חייא ורבי חייא קמיה דרבי ויתיב רבי וקאמר מנין
>   לשחיטה שהוא בתלוש שנאמר {בראשית כב-י} ויקח את המאכלת לשחוט
>
> Rav was once sitting behind Rabbi Chiya, while Rabbi Chiya was sitting
>   in front of Rebbi, and he (Rebbi) was saying "How do we know that
>   shechita must be performed with something that is unattached (from the
>   ground)? As the verse states ([Bereishit 22:10](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8217#v=10)): "And he took the knife
>   in his hand, to shecht."